# How to secure a folder access through .htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

So I have a folder that going to be used for storing some files (pdf) but I need to restrict access to it from the web, and I was suggested to do it with `.htaccess` configuration file. The problem is that I literally have no clue what to write in the file. I have looked onto example from other file in the project but that didn't help.

The thing is that these files should be available for uploading, in the folder, through `FTP/SFTP` or `SCP`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

You just need to create a `.htaccess` file in that folder with this line:

```
Deny from all
```

**Approach 2:**

Move that folder a level above your `DOCUMENT_ROOT`

Comment: I tried that. Didn't work... I also manually changed the CHMOD to 0777 and still no progress.

Comment: `Deny from all` definitely works. Just keep `.htaccess` file mode as `0644`

Comment: +1 for approach 2 - no need to put it in a folder that's web accessible if you don't want it web accessible.